# How can I enumerate a radiobuttonlist in .NET?

Tags: asp.net, radiobuttonlist

How can I enumerate a radiobuttonlist in .NET?

Comment: perhaps you are asking how to databind an enum to a radiobuttonlist?

Answer (score 3):

```
foreach (ListItem item in RadioButtonList1.Items)
{
    if (item .Selected == true)
    {
       Response.Write("You selected " + rbtn.Text);
    }
}
```

Comment: I think this should be -> foreach(ListItem item in RadioButtonList1.Items){}

Answer (score 0):

Enumerate its [Items collection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listcontrol.items.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Not really sure what you're asking here - but if you just want to enumerate thru the items, its...

```
foreach (var item in MyRbl.Items)
{
   // do something with the current item.
}
```

If you're trying to get the value, just use .SelectedValue

If you're trying to do it client side to get the selected value - you could use jQuery to get the selected value...

```
var selected = jQuery('#<%= MyRbl.ClientID %> input:checked').val();
```

Answer (score 0):

RadioButtonList.Items is a ListItemCollection which implements IEnumerable.